# How push route to another path in react-redux connected component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i wan't to make conditional routing in my component. I'm using react-redux. I have tried different things like but getting undefined error.

```
this.props.history.push('/pathname')
```

so what i wan't to do, on component will mount i'm checking some boolean value from my redux state if this value will return false i want to redirect user to another route.

my component is:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

class SomeComponent extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
        this.props.someFunc()
        if ( this.props.userLogin[0].isUserLogin === false ) {
            /// here i want to redirect to another route 
        } 
    }
render() {
   return(
     <div>Some Content</div>
   )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userLogin: state.UserLogin,
  })

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      someFunc: bindActionCreators(someAction, dispatch)
    }
  } 

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeComponent)
```

Like in example i want to redirect in component will mount user to another path. How i can do that?

Comment: Are you using react-router-dom to control the history state?

Answer (score 0):

You need Redirect

```
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

{boolFlag && <Redirect  to="/hello" />}  // put this in render
```

Comment: its how?  {this.props.userLogin[0].isUserLogin === false && <Redirect  to="/hello" />}

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "history is undefined"?
You can get history from parent component